# How to request API without API Explorer

Tags: docusignapi

I do not have any previous knowledge of calling APIs, so I am using API explorer to download PDFs of existing templates on my DocuSign developer account. However, I need to download about 500 of my templates so that I could change them, but I do not know how to exactly call and generate the PDF without the API Explorer. Would anyone be kind enough to explain to me the process of how to use API without the Explorer? I am trying to use TemplateDocuments:get

[API Explorer Link](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/templates/templatedocuments/get/?explorer=true)

Answer (score 0):

You can download Postman and then use [DocuSign Postman Collection](https://docusign.github.io/postman-collections/) to call the APIs or you can use [DocuSign Code Launchers](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/code-launchers/#examples-and-languages) to be able to create scripts in any language you prefer that does that for you